# Trying to start Biitlocker I get "This device can't use a Trusted Platform Module."

Tags: partitioning, bitlocker, tpm, windows-10-pro

I am trying to upgrad a 500GB SATA disk that was bitlocker encrypted to a 2TB disk.
Here's what I have done so far.
1. Turn off bitlocker on the source disk.  This was necessary to be able to expand the partition on the target disk.  A bitlocked partition apparently can't be expanded.
2. Used EaseUS Partition Master to migrate the OS to the new disk.  I tried using Clonezilla but could not get the resulting disk to boot.  (bcdboot did not help)
Many hours later I have the new disk installed, booting up, and mounting as C: 
But when I try to restart Bitlocker I get the following message,

> This device can't use a Trusted Platform Module.  Your administrator must set the "Allow Bitlocker without a compatible TPM" option in the "Require additional authentication at startup" policy for OS volumes.

The system does have a TPM v 1.2 and it is initialized.  The TPM management plugin reports that "The TPM is ready for use."

Am I going to have to re-initialize my TPM?

Comment: Was it initialized by Windows itself?

Comment: It was a while ago so I don't remember the exact process but I think so.  I was using bitlocker on the earlier disk and I think I initialized the TPM when I turned on bitlocker at that time.

Comment: So have you set the policy mentioned in the error?  Unless you allow password authentication your current configuration will not allow you to enable BitLocker since you can't use a TPM.  If you reinitialize your TPM you better have the recover code otherwise your data will be lost.

Comment: The policy indicated in the error message suggests that I don't have a TPM but I do have one, so I'm not inclined to bypass the TPM. What I want to know is why it used to work but now it doesn't?

Comment: What build of Windows 10 are you running?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, Version 1803, Build 17134.765

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed this problem by doing a system re-install.  Never really found the root cause but the re-install allowed the TPM to be used again.